# the nav bar won't go to the center

Tags: html, css

Whatever I do I can't get the navigation to center.

I have a wrapper and the navigation bar has an underline across this div. The top of the buttons are rounded of so it just looks like they are coming out of the bottom border.

I've tried searching for a good way to center them. A lot of people use margin auto or margin 0 auto. Other people also use this in combination with display inline-block but then the border gets cut off from the nav buttons.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about me.html">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="cv.html">CV</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#nav {
    margin: auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#nav ul {
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    list-style:none;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    width: 120px;
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px / 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(100,100,100)),              to(rgb(132,132,132)));
    background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(200,200,200), rgb(232,232,232));
}

#nav li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #383838;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

For the ease for you i've also put it in a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ge702rna/

Really hope someone can help me out because i've got my hands tied up in my hair right now.

Probally i'm just doing something simple wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add **text-align:center;**

```
#nav {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align:center; /* <-- ADD THIS LINE */
}
```

Comment: Really thanks. I knew it was something simple. I'll accept the answer when I can(11 min)

Comment: Interesting to note: because `#nav li` is set as `display: inline;`, you can center the `li` elements with `text-align: center;`.

Answer (score 0):

I just change the `width` in

```
#nav {
margin: auto;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 77%;    //changed
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Are you looking for this..[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ge702rna/8/)